# SwiftUI: How to add gesture state without property wrapper?

Tags: swift, binding, swiftui, gesture, gesture-state

How can I add gesture state without property wrapper/intermediate between @GestureState and squanced gestures updating modifier.

In the case of bindings we can do :

```
@Binding value: Bool = false
```

then

```
let binding = Binding<Bool>(get: { self.value }, set { self.value = $0 }) 

then .updating(bidning) instead of .updating($value)
```

How to achieve something like this with @GestureState to intercept its value changes?
I need it as in case of long press followed by drag I have no callbacks called on change from .pressing to .inactive state (like in Apple example)